Unity C# - Tuple must contain at least two elements - error
I am trying to update discord activities while playing my game in unity by DiscordGameSDK. I am weak in this area, so I admit that I copied everything from the guide, but I got stuck with this error:
CS8124:


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Discord;

public class DiscordManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    Discord.Discord discord;

    public static DiscordManager Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        discord = new Discord.Discord(1317541816798806167, (long)CreateFlags.Default);

        UpdateRichPresence();
    }

    public void UpdateRichPresence()
    {
        ActivityManager activityManager = discord.GetActivityManager();
        Activity activity = new()
        {
            Details = "Playing Adventure Masters",
            State = "In main menu"
        };

        activityManager.UpdateActivity(activity, (res) =>
        {
            if(res == Result.Ok)
            {
                Debug.Log("Ustawiono status");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Nie ustawiono statusu Discord");
            }
        });
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        discord.RunCallbacks();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        discord.Dispose();
    }
}

I reaserched something in the internet but I didn't find anything helpful. On the official unity Discord server someone told me it's probably a syntax error.

What version of Unity are you using? The error is because you're using new() which was introduced in C# 9.0, but Unity 6 claims to support C# 9, so I'm guessing you're on Unity 5 or earlier?

Okay, how do can I check that?

If you don't know what version of Unity you're using, I suspect you're going to have other problems soon...

What line is line 33? If that is the new() as suggested by @Dai, then using new Activity() may fix that

@Dai note that Unity 6 (released 2024) is not the direct version after Unity 5 (released 2015)  ;) There is almost a decade between them as in between there was also Unity 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021 and 2022 ^^ Unity 6 is basically a "rebrand" and the LTS version of 2023

Tuple syntax existing and the lack of new() places this around ~Unity 2018.1, or you're building for .NET Framework 2.0
